# AuthUserFile in htaccess can be url?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, .htpasswd

i have this htaccess :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName " Vip User Only

AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile c:\inetpub\htpasswd
Require valid-user

<FilesMatch ".(jpg|gif|png|tiff|jpeg|html)$">
Allow from any
Satisfy any
</FilesMatch>
```

i want to remotely read htpasswd from another server ?

e.g : this htpasswd is in Server A and i want too use htaccess in Server B with **Server A**'s htpasswd !

is this possible ?

Comment: The AuthUserFile directive sets the name of a textual file containing the list of users and passwords for user authentication. File-path is the path to the user file. If it is not absolute, it is treated as relative to the ServerRoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation of [`AuthUserFile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile)

> *File-path* is the path to the user file.

There's no mention of URI anywhere. To the contrary, it advises (rightly!) to make the file inaccessible from the web

> **Security**
>
> Make sure that the AuthUserFile is stored outside the document tree of the web-server. Do not put it in the directory that it protects. Otherwise, clients may be able to download the AuthUserFile.

Otherwise anybody could download the file, and crack all your passwords.